# Render props component throws Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make my own debounce input element, where I could send whichever input component I need like textarea and input and make it debounce. I have made a debounceComponent that looks like this:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

const useDebounce = (callback, delay) => {
  const debouncedFn = useCallback(
    debounce((...args) => callback(...args), delay),
    [delay] // will recreate if delay changes
  );
  return debouncedFn;
};

function DebouncedInput(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.initialValue);
  const debouncedSave = useDebounce(
    (nextValue) => props.onChange(nextValue),
    1000
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value: nextValue } = event.target;
    setValue(nextValue);
    debouncedSave(nextValue);
  };

  return props.renderProps({ ...props, handleChange, value });

  //return <textarea value={value} onChange={handleChange} rows={5} cols={50} />;
}

export default DebouncedInput;
```

And this is how I use it:

```
 <DebouncedInput
    initialValue={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    rows={5}
    cols={50}
    renderProps={(props) => <TextArea {...props} />}
  />
```

But, if I use it like that I get an error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {dispatchConfig, _targetInst, _dispatchListeners, _dispatchInstances,
> nativeEvent, type, target, currentTarget, eventPhase, bubbles,
> cancelable, timeStamp, defaultPrevented, isTrusted,
> isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

You can see the codesandbox for it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-bush-i8iyu?file=/src/App.js:336-513).
What am I doing wrong here, how can I fix this?

Comment: This is because in your ```App``` in ```handleChange``` you set the value to the event object. The parameter of the function is, in fact, an event, so you can get the value by ```event.target.value```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `DebouncedInput` component change the return statement.

from

```js
return props.renderProps({ ...props, handleChange, value });
```

to

```js
return props.renderProps({ ...props, onChange: handleChange, value });
```

```js
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

const useDebounce = (callback, delay) => {
  const debouncedFn = useCallback(
    debounce((...args) => callback(...args), delay),
    [delay] // will recreate if delay changes
  );
  return debouncedFn;
};

function DebouncedInput(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.initialValue);
  const debouncedSave = useDebounce(
    (nextValue) => props.onChange(nextValue),
    1000
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value: nextValue } = event.target;
    setValue(nextValue);
    debouncedSave(nextValue);
  };

  return props.renderProps({ ...props, onChange: handleChange, value });

}

export default DebouncedInput;
```

Also, instead of spreading all the props to the component, pass only the props that are relevant to the input element. So, in this case when calling `props.renderProps({ ...props, onChange: handleChange, value })` all the props that's being received by `DebouncedInput` component are directly passed to the `input` or `TextArea` component which means `renderProps` is also being passed. But in general `input` or `TextArea` might not have `initialValue` , `renderProps` as props, that will throw a warning.

There are different ways of in order not to get such warnings, below is one of the way

- Spread the required props to `DebouncedInput` and the props of input component as `rest` parameter

```js
function DebouncedInput({initialValue, renderProps, onChange, ...rest}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const debouncedSave = useDebounce(
    (nextValue) => onChange(nextValue),
    1000
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value: nextValue } = event.target;
    setValue(nextValue);
    debouncedSave(nextValue);
  };

  return renderProps({ ...rest, onChange: handleChange, value });

}
```

- Pass all the input/TextArea related props inside another object like below. Here I'm passing all the related props that I want to send as part of input component I'm wrapping inside `inputProps` and passing the same through `renderProps`.

```js
<DebouncedInput
    initialValue={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderProps={(props) => <TextArea {...props} />}
    inputProps={{rows:5, cols:50}}
  />
```

```js
function DebouncedInput(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.initialValue);
  const debouncedSave = useDebounce(
    (nextValue) => props.onChange(nextValue),
    1000
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value: nextValue } = event.target;
    setValue(nextValue);
    debouncedSave(nextValue);
  };

  return props.renderProps({ ...props.inputProps, onChange: handleChange, value });

}
```

- Since you are passing the `props` and the `component` also from the same place, you can do it in a simple way like below

```js
 <DebouncedInput
    initialValue={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    renderProps={(props) => <TextArea {...props} rows={5} cols={50}/>}
  />
```

```js
function DebouncedInput(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.initialValue);
  const debouncedSave = useDebounce(
    (nextValue) => props.onChange(nextValue),
    1000
  );

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { value: nextValue } = event.target;
    setValue(nextValue);
    debouncedSave(nextValue);
  };

  return props.renderProps({ onChange: handleChange, value });

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is there a way of avoiding the renderProps warning for TextArea or input element?

Comment: Yes, We can do that. I have updated my answer with the different ways with which we can avoid the warning.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I'm happy to have helped you :)